# gradle: Duplicate value for resources coming from multiple external libraries

Tags: android, gradle

I have a situation where I am trying to add two dependencies that have resources conflict.

```
Duplicate value for resource 'attr/userInfoAddressTextStyleValue' with config 'DEFAULT' and product ''. The resource was previously defined here:*location of the second library*
```

You can say they have a bunch of resource value ids in common. I am trying to figure out how to keep both libraries in the project.

Comment: If the libraries are yours, just change the names

Comment: Unfortunately, the libs don't belong to me.

Comment: What are those libraries? Maybe you don't need both at the same time

Comment: Both of them are private libs. 
This question is more for the curiosity/knowledge on how to solve the issue, even if it's solvable or not.

Comment: Usually when two libraries share some similar resource names it's because they aren't needed at the same time. I don't know of another solution other than removing the duplicates, sorry.

Comment: But that's true, I really don't need them at the same time. So I have a Feature Toggle and I want to pick the correct lib out of those two based on the FT value.

Comment: Maybe contact the developers or compile two separate versions of the app

Answer (score 0):

If it is open source then you can add them like new module and then you can edit source code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).